# How to keep my panel refreshed... it disappears

Tags: c#

In C# (GDI+) when I draw something on the panel using the class Graphics... when I pass another window forground (on the panel) everything I have drawn disapears...!!

How to fix it ?

Thank you...

Comment: Any chance to see your code or you expect us to guess?

Comment: Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black)), new point(3,3), new point(12,15));

// after that the line is drawn but when I minimize (for example) the window form of my program and maximize it again the line will be disapeared.

Comment: As i already answered you need to draw everything on the paint event

Comment: Tank you very much for your answer... It works, but accually I couldn't solve the problem properly because I can't control when the event "paint" occurs. I want the event to occur when I click a button, not immediatly after debugging... Is it possible to do this?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Easy, just put your code inside the paint method but don't draw anything if some flag is not set, when the user clicks your button just set the flag and invalidate de panel (Panel.Invalidate()), that will force the panel to be redraw, making your code paint your stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You need to paint everything on the Paint event.

Basically nothing painted is persistent because the windows needs to redraw itself again after it's overlaped, minimized, etc. So, if you want to paint something you need to do it on the Paint event, basically repainting it every time is needed.

If you only need to paint your stuff after the user clicks on a button, just put your drawing code on the paint event but don't do anything if some flag is not set, your button will only need to set the flag and call the Invalidate method of your panel to force it to redraw itself running your code on the process.